# Laravel model delete method not triggered

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I've got a `message` model and a `reaction` model. So when I remove a `message` all `files` from a reaction should also be removed.

But my `delete` method from my `reaction model` is not being `triggered`?

In my `Message` model:

```
public function delete()
{
   $this->reactions()->delete();
   return parent::delete();
}
```

In my `Reaction` model:

```
public function delete()
{
    $files = $this->files;
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $this->destroyFile($file);
    }

    return parent::delete();
}
```

So when I `dd('test');` it never reach that method.

Comment: Is it possible for you to do this in your migrations, i.e. does reactions have a foreign key that references the id on messages?

Comment: @craig_h My file table is using morph relations. So it's only associated with a user (foreign key).

Comment: OK, that explains why you can't use a cascade. You should really be placing your delete method inside your MessagesController, not your model and then you can perform this action all in one go.

Comment: I thought it was possible to do this in a ```delete``` method on the model. Then every time a reaction is removed all files are being removed aswel.

Comment: I think what you want is an `eloquent event` which allows you to listen to events on a model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events

Comment: Actually, I see what you are doing now. Remember that `$this->reactions()` returns the query builder, so it isn't calling delete on your model. Instead you need to do: `$this->reactions->delete();`

Comment: When I do that I get: ```Method delete does not exist.``` But eloquent events looks great. Going to try that.